# Blog Search Engines : is there any of them still alive (2022)?

Tags: search, search-engine, blog

All Blog Search Engines pointed by Wikipedia are LONG DEAD: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Blog_search_engines .

Is there any working today? I'd like to engage with the current blogosphere, but manually searching and ranking them is really a job that doesn't pays itself.

Comment: You might be better off trying to "spider" blogs on your own, by finding a few and then looking at what they link to.  I also find a lot of interesting stuff linked from, for instance, Hacker News.

Comment: @BrenBarn Wouldn't most outbound links be for non-blog pages? I'm skeptical that bloggers are indeed reading and blogging about other blogs. That's why I need a search engine: because manually searching for blog posts does not leads me to other blog posts. They are all scattered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one called [Blog Surf](https://blogsurf.io/).  According to the info, it searches a hand-curated set of (currently) about 900 blogs.  That's not a huge reach, but it does seem to be only blogs.

Comment: Great find this one of yours! "Hand-curated" seems pretty 'pre-Google'. But blogs are pretty oldschool too, so I'll take a look at it, probably contact them too, clarify some points about their service, etc. and I'll do a feedback here later.

Comment: It was online on [14 Feb 2023](http://web.archive.org/web/20230214110542/https://blogsurf.io/), but is giving a "Server not found" message today. Maybe the last blog search engine died this year?