# Blog search engines: are any of them still alive?

Tags: search, search-engine, blog

All 15 blog search engines pointed by Wikipedia are **long dead**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Blog_search_engines .

Is there any working today? I'd like to engage with the current blogosphere, but manually searching and ranking them is really a job that doesn't pays itself.

[I asked the same question last year](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/83975/blog-search-engines-is-there-any-of-them-still-alive-2022) and got the only answer: [BlogSurf](https://blogsurf.io), that died at the beginning of 2023. Is there any other blog search engine alive in 2023?

Answer (score 3):

One of the recent contenders which is gaining popularity is [feedle](https://feedle.world/).

Few smaller search engines provide filters for searching blogs and “small web” sites, see [Marginalia](https://search.marginalia.nu/) (with "Blogosphere" domains) and [Stract](https://stract.com/) (with “Indieweb & blogroll” optic).

Kagi also recently [announced Kagi Small Web](https://blog.kagi.com/small-web), which is part of their (paid) search and also provides [StumbleUpon-style content discovery](https://kagi.com/smallweb).